# Atmel SAM C21 stuck in Reset_Handler

Tags: atmel

I was trying to implement the watchdog functionality using ASF in an SAMC21 xplained pro and after flashing the code the device started behaving oddly. If I try to run any code it looks like it is not doing anything.

If I try to start debugging it goes directly to `Reset_Handler` function.

I tried erasing the hole code and also disabling the watchdog timer in the fuses but nothing changes.

What can I do, or what other information should I provide to get help with this issue?

Comment: well, sounds like your watchdog might be doing its job?

Comment: but how can I disable it? If I try disabling it in software it doesn't work

Comment: You do realize that the Reset_Handler is where **all** code must start, don't you? If you are single-stepping then this is were everything begins.

Comment: The problem was I was not powering off the uC after disabling the WDT lock feature.

Comment: @jagjordi - you should post your solution as an answer and accept it once the self answer timer expires.  Otherwise the question will forever show as unresolved and keep getting churned back up every couple of months.

Comment: I'll  do   that     thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I was not powering off the uC after changing the configuration of the WDT. Doing that solved the problem